# Html relative url behaviour

Tags: html

I have a situation where I need to call a path relative to the current url pretty straight forward, however for some reason when I make the execute the url part of the current url gets lost and I do not know why.

In other words I am currently a this webpage.

```
localhost:<port>/X/View/12345
```

and in my html I have a basic anchor tag:

```
<a class="btn btn-link w-full" href="Export"><i class="fa fa-file-excel-o pull-left"></i><span class="pull-right">Export</span></a>
```

I would think that when I click the link the browser would go:

```
localhost:<port>/X/View/12345/Export
```

However I end up with:

```
localhost:<port>/X/View/Export
```

I was hoping someone could give some points at what to look at, or why this could be happening?

Note:

- I cannot update my link to say `href="12345/Export"`.
- There also   doesn't appear to be a base path set on the page.
- The RequestUrl is `localhost:<port>/X/View/12345`

I can't seem to work out why I am loosing the id part of the url? :(

Comment: is `Export` a file or directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there is no slash after 12345 it's considered by your browser a file not the directory

In     localhost:/X/View/12345

to go to localhost:/X/View/12345/Export

Relative url has to be

```
<a class="btn btn-link w-full" href="12345/Export"><i class="fa fa-file-excel-o pull-left"></i><span class="pull-right">Export</span></a>
```

either that or you have to do a url rewrite or redirect for  /X/View/12345 to be /X/View/12345/

Comment: Hey figure that :) Thanks